# Потдерживает ли Андроид 12 перенос преложений на карту памяти?

Tags: android

Потдерживает ли Андроид 12 перенос преложений на карту памяти?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно поддерживает

Перенос приложений на карту памяти:

1 Убедитесь, что карта памяти вставлена в устройство.

2 На начальном экране коснитесь меню приложений.

3 Найдите и коснитесь Настройки > Приложения.

4 Коснитесь клавиши На SD-карту tab.

5 Выберите приложение, затем коснитесь Переместить на SD-карту.

Comment: Спасибо большое!